# How to create dashed div borders like on the image here

Tags: html, css

basically, I would like for each of these 4 boxes to be a div and then have a class preferably for each type of border to create a border with that kind of shadow or something

But I have no clue where to start except create a border

[image]

Comment: The borders in your ""design"" are inconsistent. Out of curiosity, who told you to make them?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sometime customers produce inconsistent specifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this with the literal border attribute in CSS, but with a little fanagling, you could wrap that div in another div which uses the repeating gradient property as such:

```css
.wrap {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, black, black 5px, white 5px, white 10px);
  
  border: 1px solid black;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.real {
  background-color: white;

  border:1px solid black;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="real">
    <p>Sup</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where you can change the margin around the inner div to replicate increase border size and you can mess around with the values in the repeating-linear-gradient property to increase amount of lines shown and their color.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the gradient percentages to get what you want

```css
.border-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 20rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2rem solid transparent;
    border-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right top, black 10%, white 11%) 15%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="border-box"></div>
```

Comment: better use the value of the slice the same as the border to have a good result .. in your case 2rem = 2*16 = 30 : https://jsfiddle.net/vg0n15cm/